# How to solve this intent filters issue. I am unable to recognize it?

Tags: android, intentfilter

Main activity.java

```
package com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
EditText edit;
Button sms1,sms2;
String Abc = "ABC";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sms1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sms1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "sms to" + edit.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    sms2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    sms2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "sms to:" + edit.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo.SMS_INTENT",Uri.parse(uri));
            i.putExtra("from",Abc);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
}



}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
         android:name=".MySmsActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
             <action android:name="com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo.SMS_INTENT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:scheme="smsto" />
          </intent-filter>
     </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

LogCat

```
    09-22 09:10:48.731  18542-18542/com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo       E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo, PID: 18542
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo.SMS_INTENT dat=sms to:1345677 (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1723)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1491)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3436)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3393)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3644)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3607)
        at com.example.webwerks.intentfilterdemo.MyActivity$2.onClick(MyActivity.java:40)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me with this error i am unable to resolve it as i am new to android
I am not getting the exact error in this.
Looking forward the replies at your warliest
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue was sorted 
in main activity.java i used this:

```
 String uri = "sms to:" + edit.getText().toString();
```

whereas in manifest i declared it as

```
<data android:scheme="smsto" />
```

so there was a change in the schema

anyways thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

May be it is coming because you have not given permission for internet, please try by adding below permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: There is nothing in the app that uses internet.But then too i tried but it didnt helped me out